# How to save a GeoDataFrame with many geometry columns (polygon, point and linestring) to a geojson file (or a csv file)?

Tags: python, geopandas

I am trying to save the following GeoDataFrame with columns (geometry, area, centroid, and boundary) to a json file using `df.to_file('result.geojson', driver="GeoJSON")`:

[image: geodataframe]

However, I get the following error because I have centroid and boundary columns.
`TypeError: Cannot interpret '<geopandas.array.GeometryDtype object at 0x7fb7fff86940>'` as a data type.
This works perfectly fine when there is only geometry column and area column.

Also when I try to save it as a csv file and then read it back as geopandas file, I am only able to convert geometry into datatype geometry. However, centroid and boundary show as object datatype. How do I convert them to geometry datatype?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551), instead provide the necessary data to reproduce the problem, ideally as a [minimal reproducible example](/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also, always include the [full stacktrace](//realpython.com/python-traceback) - it's critical for debugging.

Comment: the [geojson](https://geojson.org/) format does not support having multiple geometries per feature. csv doesn't have any object encoding whatsoever. you could try [parquet](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.to_parquet.html), though this depends on the version 0.1 concept proposal and may be unstable. Another thing you could do is convert your secondary geometry columns to WKT/WKB (string/bytes) or e.g. for the centroids just extract the x and y coordinates as individual float columns.

Comment: Only one geometry is possible in GeoJson as well as Geopandas. Anyway, if you just need to save and load files for ongoing work, write them with pickle. Pandas can write files with pickle, so can geopandas. You will be able to recall your work situation as it is.

Answer (score 1):

- as per comments, both **geopandas** and **geojson** only support one geometry per feature
- hence your data frame is polygons as geometry and other columns are series of objects (**shapely** objects)
- have simulated data set.  This clearly demonstrates your data structure is not normalised.  *boundary, centroid* and *area* are calculated columns. Hence in relational theory not normalised
- this can be saved as *CSV* **shapely** objects will be encoded as *WKT*
- this can then simply be loaded, with second step to decode WKT back into **shapely** objects
- have demonstrated this works by plotting geometries loaded from CSV

```
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd
import shapely.geometry
from pathlib import Path

gdf = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path("naturalearth_lowres"))

# derive columns in question...
gdf["boundary"] = gdf["geometry"].apply(lambda p: p.boundary )
gdf["centroid"] = gdf["geometry"].apply(lambda p: p.centroid )
gdf["area"] = gdf["geometry"].apply(lambda p: p.area )

# save as CSV shapely.wkt.dumps will be implicitly used
gdf.to_csv(Path.cwd().joinpath("SO_geom.csv"), index=False)

# load encoded dataframe
df = pd.read_csv(Path.cwd().joinpath("SO_geom.csv"))
# decode geometry columns as strings back into shapely objects
for c in ["geometry","boundary","centroid"]:
    df[c] = df[c].apply(shapely.wkt.loads)

# finally reconstruct geodataframe
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df)
# show it has worked
gdf.plot()
gpd.GeoSeries(gdf["boundary"]).plot()
gpd.GeoSeries(gdf["centroid"]).plot()
```

[image]